# ASP.NET MVC 3 - two forms, two ActionResult but one Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a new asp.net mvc 3 project with following structure:

**Views:**
*/Home/Index.cshtml*

```
@{
    Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", "POST");
}
<input id="name" type="text" />
<input id="submit_1" type="submit" value="submit" />
@{
    Html.EndForm();
}

@{
    Html.BeginForm("FindTeacher", "Home", "POST");
}
<input id="name" type="text" />
<input id="submit_2" type="submit" value="submit" />
@{
    Html.EndForm();
}
```

**Controller:**
*/Controllers/HomeController.cs*

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string name)
    {
        //call the model FindStudent() and set the ViewData
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FindTeacher(string name)
    {
        //Call the FindTeacher () and set the ViewData
        return View();
    }
}
```

The submit_1 is works, because it found the ActionResult of Index, however, when i click submit_2, it say cannot find FindTeacher Controller.

So how can i do?

Comment: `@using(Html.BeginForm(...)) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult FindTeacher(string name) 
{ 
  // do updates 
  return RedirectToAction("Index"); or 
  return Index(); 
}
```

Comment: I set a breakpoint on return RedirectToAction("Index"), it occur. but i cannot get the [name] parameter, it goes null.

Comment: I make it works, the input should have name attribue, not only [id] like webform.

Answer (score 1):

`"POST"` is wrong; it should be `FormMethods.Post`.

Because of that, your forms are actually submitting GET requests.

`Index` works because you have a different action that responds to GET requests to `/Index`.
`FindTeacher` fails because there is no GET for that action.